# Viewing previous processes/application activity on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

I was recently wrongly accused of cheating on an online test I took on a MacBook air running Catalina 10.15.7 about a month ago. The allegation is that I was communicating with other students during the test. Is there was a way I could retrieve a log of the processes/applications that were running on my mac that day, at that time in order to prove no communication-based apps were running during the test?

Comment: What evidence did your accuser give?

Answer (score 1):

Not really - and the more you try to prove with technical details, you might be sabotaging yourself. It’s easier for you to tamper with the process list than it is to cheat on an online test, so I wouldn’t go down that path at all.

I would just ask the accuser or referee how you can demonstrate mastery of the material and remedy the situation. It’s awful when your character is accused and it’s awful when you get caught cheating, so either way, you are in a bad situation and grasping for a technicality isn’t going to help you. This is a social problem, not one that can be dismissed without two conditions:

1. Referee has to be agreeable to a technical summary and adjudication.
2. You can in no way be involved in the preparation of any exculpatory data. A forensic investigator has to handle the preservation, preparation, analysis and evaluation of any technical evidence.

Comment: what if I hired some kind of cyber forensic investigator to go through my laptop and report findings? There's hard no evidence that I was communicating with other students, I'm having a really hard time proving that I did not communicate with people during this test.

Comment: Down that road madness lies. Even if there were some way to know exactly what processes were running at that point in time, there is nothing to stop your accuser from claiming you modified the system so it did not report on a process in question, or to accuse you of communicating with a student outside of the computer. It seems to me that you have a social problem, which will need a social - not a technical - solution. (If you are being accused without evidence, it seems fair to refute the accusation - also without evidence.)

Comment: @needhelp The running of a process on a Mac is in itself not logged anywhere - so even a professional cyber forensic investigator cannot determine whether or not a specific process ran at a specific time in the past on your Mac.

Comment: Of course you’re struggling to prove anything, @needhelp you can not be involved in the proof of evidence. Find out what the referee wants and pay for it and accept your loss of money and the result they come up with. If the person you hire has scruples, they will take $50 and tell you what I did, forget it and work with the human. If they are unscrupulous you could spend more or less and they may or may not convince the accuser that a mistake was made.